# Question on retain attribute with @property and @synthesize

Tags: objective-c

I'm still pretty new to Objective-C coding (as evidenced by this question) and I think I'm not completely understanding how using the retain attribute in a @property declaration works.

Here is an example class:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *myArray; 
}

@property (retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

My understanding was that adding the retain attribute to the @property declaration (and using the necessary @synthesize delcaration in the implementation file) will basically do the following setter and getter for me:

```
- (void)setMyArray:(NSMutableArray *)newArray {
    myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:newArray];
    [newArray release];
}

- (NSMutableArray *)myArray {
    return myArray;
}
```

Is this accurate or am I mistaken on how the retain attribute works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the retain attribute will actually generate this code:

```
- (void)setMyArray:(NSMutableArray *)newArray {
    [newArray retain];
    [myArray release];
    myArray = newArray;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)myArray {
    return myArray;
}
```

The reason the **retain** method is called on newArray before **release** on the old value is that if newArray and myArray are the same object, the array will be released before it is retained again.

Comment: so if I override the setter method myself, I should follow this format of retain and release?

Comment: @cpjolicoeur: That depends, the actual implementations are even more sophisticated with locks to prevent threading issues.

Comment: yes, that's exactly how the compiler generates it (I have been trying to find a reference to this, but I can't seem to find it right now)

Comment: I believe that the setter call is surrounded by `if (newArray == myArray)` to gain a little bit of performance when assigning the same object, but that's basically an implementation detail.

Comment: Are you sure about the return [[myArray retain] autorelease];
. Won't this cause loads of objects to be hanging in the `AutoReleasePool` if you go on assigning new objects? if `self` was release all of it's `myArray` would still linger until the pool was killed, even though nothing else in the program was referencing them.

Comment: It's necessary. Imagine you've got some code and you access that property: `id name = theObject.name;` After that you change the name: `theObject.name = @"Someone";`. Now you try to access the old name, which has been released: `NSLog(name);` This is going to crash.

Comment: Apple does it this way, just try out the AppleScripts in Xcode to create accessors. I suppose it would also be possible to use autorelease in the setter instead of the getter. No idea how that works performance wise…

Comment: The code it generates is not exactly equivalent to that, but roughly. This code is nonatomic, at the very least. And I'm pretty sure the `[[myArray retain] autorelease]` edit was correct, as gs demonstrated.

Comment: @gs: you have a point. We should disassemble the generated code to know for sure :-)

Comment: Try it: http://pastebin.com/f312a55f3. This prints for me: `*** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x203c of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking` Here's some opensource code of Apple: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-371.2/runtime/Accessors.subproj/objc-accessors.m

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to do it right. Take a look at the article [Memory and thread-safe custom property methods](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/memory-and-thread-safe-custom-property.html) on Cocoa with Love by Matt Gallagher.

Here's *one* implementation that works, heavily inspired by [that excellent article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/memory-and-thread-safe-custom-property.html).

```
- (void)setSomeString:(NSString *)aString {
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (someString != aString) // not necessary, but might improve
                                   // performance quite a bit
        {
            [aString retain];
            [someString release];
            someString = aString;
        }
    }
}

- (NSString *)someString {
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        id result = [someString retain];
    }
    return [result autorelease];
}
```

Comment: I believe all the locking action only occurs if you declare it atomic.

Comment: @ruibm: Atomic is the default. See http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW28

Answer (score 0):

`retain` will not do a copy of the new value. It will retain the new value and release the old one.